# How to call only recent hit api and abort the session of previous called api in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Actually, Here I am going to call an API on the bases of a word which I want to search and the words which are stared from my searching words are searched properly but here the problem is the if i typed a big word like that length is more than 3 so the API hit's 3 times and also return the result related to those words but in this case I just want to override that API calls and run only last one API with the complete word which I typed so, Is there any way to handle this situation.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because I'd actually like to see other answers. Have you tried added a 50-200ms delay before sending a new request? This would probably eliminate some of the issue. Also, do you have any flag to indicate there is an existing request?

Comment: Yes.This is what the lodash `debounce` or `throttle` function do.If after `wait` seconds you don't call another api,the previous function will execute.But if you call another api in `wait ` seconds,the previous call in canceled.

Comment: If this can not work.Maybe you can use `axios`,try to cancel your previous api call by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button for start searching

Also you can use `onSubmitEditing` to start calling the api after the user type a complete word . otherwise this is inevitable to handle this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `debounce` function.It will delay your function call,and just call the recent one.

```
function debounce (fn, delay) {
    let timer   = null;

    return function () {
    let args = arguments;
    let context = this;

        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);

            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }, delay);
        } else {
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }, delay);
        }
    }
}

function apiCall(){
// your code
}

function realCall(){
  return debounce(apiCall,300)
}
```

Comment: not working properly the last one call first but after that other's also call.